# How to add a "Print" button on MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, printing, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm trying to add a button "Print" on the navigation item of `MFMailComposeViewController` on iOS 9. Is this possible?

Comment: where u want to add it exactly?

Comment: I don't think you can modify things like that in Apple's View Controllers. Even if you do subclass it, though I could be mistaken. The natural way to do go about this would be to suggest to your users to print from Apple's Mail app. Interesting idea though, so it may be worth submitting a Feature Request with Apple.